# How to change python version in ansible-builder image

Tags: ansible

By default, ansible-builder image use Python 3.8
How python version can be changed so that image uses other python versions for playbook execution?

BASE_IMAGE=quay.io/ansible/ansible-builder:latest

Comment: You need to provide more information. Which image are you using?

Comment: updated in the question